# Параллельное выполнение двух функций PHP

Tags: php, cron

Например есть файл с 2 функциями.

Как сделать так что бы они запустились одновременно и начали выполняться параллельно друг другу?

Comment: Это называется многопоточность. Гуглите реализацию многопоточность в php

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev это называется асинхронность